How do I use tkraise on another frame class in Tkinter
I am currently learning to implement classes into my GUI. I know how to use tkraise normally however now its complicated.
I'm getting TypeError: login_page.widgets..sign_in() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
What I want the software to do is after I have logged in, to raise the 'Main frame'.
I have hashed my attempt of using the tkraise in the sign_in function.
Could someone explain please.
from customtkinter import *

global d_text
d_text = ''

class software(CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry('1000x800')

        
        Main = main(self)
        Login_page = login_page(self)
        Menu = menu(Main)
        Keypad = keypad(Main)
        Sub_menu = sub_menu(Main)
        Header = header(Main)
        Right_menu = right_menu(Main)
        Admin_menu = admin_menu(Main)
        self.mainloop()

class login_page(CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.configure(width=1000,height=800,fg_color='black')
        self.place(x=0,y=0)

        self.widgets()
    def widgets(self):
        
        def sign_in(self):
            if login_entryfield.get() == 'user123':
                if password_entryfield.get() == 'base12':
                    print('signed in as user')
                    #### self.Main.tkraise()
                else:
                    print('incorrect password')
                    
            else:
                print('incorrect user name')

        #widgets
        login_label = CTkLabel(self,text='Login',font = ("Arial", 20, "bold"))
        login_entryfield = CTkEntry(self, width=200)    
        password_label = CTkLabel(self,text='Password',font = ("Arial", 20, "bold"))
        password_entryfield = CTkEntry(self, width=200) 
        enter_button  = CTkButton(self,text='Login',font = ("Arial", 20, "bold"),command=sign_in)

        #layout
        login_label.place(x=300,y=100)
        login_entryfield.place(x=400,y=100)
        password_label.place(x=300,y=200)
        password_entryfield.place(x=400,y=200)
        enter_button.place(x=400,y=700)


class main(CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        super().__init__(parent) 
        self.configure(width=1000,height=800, fg_color='black',corner_radius=0)
        self.place(x=0,y=0)

class header(CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.configure(width=1000,height=50, fg_color='green',corner_radius=0)
        self.place(x=0,y=0)

class menu(CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.configure(width=450,height=450,fg_color='red',corner_radius=0)
        self.place(x=0,y=50)

class right_menu(CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.configure(height=750,width=200, fg_color='purple',corner_radius=0)
        self.place(x=800,y=50)

        fv_button = CTkButton(self,text='Fruit&Veg',width=200,height=80)
        bakery_button = CTkButton(self,text='Bakery',width=200,height=80)
        Heavy_Misc_button = CTkButton(self,text='Heavy&Misc',width=200,height=80)
        bags_button = CTkButton(self,text='Recyclable Bags',width=200,height=80)
        downarrow_btn = CTkButton(self,text='↓',width=60,height=80)
        uparrow_btn = CTkButton(self,text='↑',width=60,height=80)

        fv_button.place(x=0,y=50)
        bakery_button.place(x=0,y=160)
        Heavy_Misc_button.place(x=0,y=270)
        bags_button.place(x=0,y=380)
        downarrow_btn.place(x=0,y=490)
        uparrow_btn.place(x=70,y=490)

class admin_menu(CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.configure(width=1000,height=150, fg_color='green',corner_radius=0)
        self.place(x=0,y=650)

        open_btn = CTkButton(self,text='^',width=50,height=50, corner_radius=0)
        open_btn.place(x=20,y=30)

        Lock_btn = CTkButton(self,text='Lock', width=125, height=75,corner_radius=0)
        Lock_btn.place(x=100,y=30)

        logoff_btn = CTkButton(self,text='Log Off', width=125, height=75,corner_radius=0)
        logoff_btn.place(x=250,y=30)

        report_btn = CTkButton(self,text='Report Abuse', width=125, height=75,corner_radius=0)
        report_btn.place(x=400,y=30)

        item_search_btn = CTkButton(self,text='Item Search', width=125, height=75,corner_radius=0)
        item_search_btn.place(x=550,y=30)

        Return_btn = CTkButton(self,text='Returns', width=125, height=75,corner_radius=0)
        Return_btn.place(x=700,y=30)

        Funds_management = CTkButton(self,text='Funds Management', width=125, height=75,corner_radius=0)
        Funds_management.place(x=850,y=30)
        



class keypad(CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.configure(width=300,height=450,fg_color='green', corner_radius=0)
        self.place(x=460,y=200)

        self.widget()   
    def widget(self):
        
        def display(var):
            global d_text
            d_text += str(var)
            lb1.configure(text=d_text)

        def clear():
            global d_text
            d_text = ''
            lb1.configure(text=d_text)
        
        def backspace():
            global d_text
            d_text = d_text[ :-1]
            lb1.configure(text=d_text)

        lb1 = CTkLabel(self,text='',width=300,fg_color='blue')

        btn1 = CTkButton(self, text=7,width=50,height=50,command=lambda:display(7))
        btn2 = CTkButton(self, text=8,width=50,height=50, command=lambda: display(8))
        btn3 = CTkButton(self, text=9,width=50,height=50, command=lambda: display(9))
        btn4 = CTkButton(self, text=4,width=50,height=50, command=lambda: display(4))
        btn5 = CTkButton(self, text=5,width=50,height=50, command=lambda: display(5))
        btn6 = CTkButton(self, text=6,width=50,height=50,command=lambda: display(6))
        btn7 = CTkButton(self, text=1,width=50,height=50, command=lambda: display(1))
        btn8 = CTkButton(self, text=2,width=50,height=50,command=lambda: display(2))
        btn9 = CTkButton(self, text=3,width=50,height=50,command=lambda: display(3))
        btn0 = CTkButton(self, text=0, width=50,height=50,command=lambda: display(0))
        decbtn = CTkButton(self,text='.',width=50,height=50,command=lambda: display('.'))
        clear_btn = CTkButton(self,text='C',width=50,height=50, command=lambda: clear())
        back_btn = CTkButton(self,text='<<',width=50,height=50, command=lambda: backspace())
        multiply_btn = CTkButton(self,text='X',width=50,height=50)
        ok_btn = CTkButton(self,text='OK',width=50,height=140)
        lb1.place(x=0,y=0)
        btn1.place(x=20,y=75)
        btn2.place(x=80,y=75)
        btn3.place(x=140,y=75)
        btn4.place(x=20,y=140)
        btn5.place(x=80,y=140)
        btn6.place(x=140,y=140)
        btn7.place(x=20,y=205)
        btn8.place(x=80,y=205)
        btn9.place(x=140,y=205)
        btn0.place(x=20,y=270)
        decbtn.place(x=80,y=270)
        clear_btn.place(x=140,y=270)
        back_btn.place(x=200,y=75)
        multiply_btn.place(x=200,y=140)
        ok_btn.place(x=200,y=205)

class sub_menu(CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.configure(width=450,height=100,fg_color='yellow', corner_radius=0)
        self.place(x=0,y=450)

        self.widgets()
    def widgets(self):
        up_btn = CTkButton(self, text='↑', width=50,height=80)
        down_btn = CTkButton(self, text='↓', width=50, height=80)

        lb2 = CTkLabel(self, text='Balance due', font = ("Arial", 20, "bold"))
        lb3 = CTkLabel(self, text='0.00', font = ("Arial", 20, "bold"))
        lb4 = CTkLabel(self,text='0 items', font = ("Arial", 20, "bold"))

        up_btn.place(x=20,y=10)
        down_btn.place(x=80,y=10)
        lb2.place(x=150,y=60)
        lb3.place(x=300,y=60)
        lb4.place(x=150,y=0)

    
software()


sign_in() is an inner (or nested) function and not a class method, so argument self is not necessary.  Remove it.  Also from security point of view, don't tell user something like "incorrect user name" and "incorrect password".  Just tell them "incorrect credentials".

ok thank you. but How do I raise the Main frame?

Main is a local variable inside software.__init__(), so it cannot be accessed outside that function.  One of the way is to pass it to login_page and then pass it to login_page.widgets().

how do you pass it?

The Problem
The error you're encountering is because the sign_in function is defined inside the widgets method, making it a nested function. In this context, it does not automatically get self as its first parameter.
To fix this, you need to move the sign_in function to be a method of the login_page class instead of being inside widgets.
Additionally, to raise the main frame after a successful login, you need to pass a reference to the main frame instance to the login_page instance.
Here’s a corrected version of your code:

from customtkinter import *

global d_text
d_text = ''

class software(CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry('1000x800')

        self.Main = main(self)
        self.Login_page = login_page(self, self.Main)
        self.Menu = menu(self.Main)
        self.Keypad = keypad(self.Main)
        self.Sub_menu = sub_menu(self.Main)
        self.Header = header(self.Main)
        self.Right_menu = right_menu(self.Main)
        self.Admin_menu = admin_menu(self.Main)
        self.mainloop()

class login_page(CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent, main_frame):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.main_frame = main_frame  # Store reference to the main frame
        self.configure(width=1000, height=800, fg_color='black')
        self.place(x=0, y=0)

        self.widgets()

    def sign_in(self):
        if self.login_entryfield.get() == 'user123':
            if self.password_entryfield.get() == 'base12':
                print('signed in as user')
                self.main_frame.tkraise()  # Raise the main frame
            else:
                print('incorrect password')
        else:
            print('incorrect user name')

    def widgets(self):
        # widgets
        login_label = CTkLabel(self, text='Login', font=("Arial", 20, "bold"))
        self.login_entryfield = CTkEntry(self, width=200)
        password_label = CTkLabel(self, text='Password', font=("Arial", 20, "bold"))
        self.password_entryfield = CTkEntry(self, width=200, show='*')
        enter_button = CTkButton(self, text='Login', font=("Arial", 20, "bold"), command=self.sign_in)

        # layout
        login_label.place(x=300, y=100)
        self.login_entryfield.place(x=400, y=100)
        password_label.place(x=300, y=200)
        self.password_entryfield.place(x=400, y=200)
        enter_button.place(x=400, y=700)

class main(CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.configure(width=1000, height=800, fg_color='black', corner_radius=0)
        self.place(x=0, y=0)

class header(CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.configure(width=1000, height=50, fg_color='green', corner_radius=0)
        self.place(x=0, y=0)

class menu(CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.configure(width=450, height=450, fg_color='red', corner_radius=0)
        self.place(x=0, y=50)

class right_menu(CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.configure(height=750, width=200, fg_color='purple', corner_radius=0)
        self.place(x=800, y=50)

        fv_button = CTkButton(self, text='Fruit&Veg', width=200, height=80)
        bakery_button = CTkButton(self, text='Bakery', width=200, height=80)
        Heavy_Misc_button = CTkButton(self, text='Heavy&Misc', width=200, height=80)
        bags_button = CTkButton(self, text='Recyclable Bags', width=200, height=80)
        downarrow_btn = CTkButton(self, text='↓', width=60, height=80)
        uparrow_btn = CTkButton(self, text='↑', width=60, height=80)

        fv_button.place(x=0, y=50)
        bakery_button.place(x=0, y=160)
        Heavy_Misc_button.place(x=0, y=270)
        bags_button.place(x=0, y=380)
        downarrow_btn.place(x=0, y=490)
        uparrow_btn.place(x=70, y=490)

class admin_menu(CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.configure(width=1000, height=150, fg_color='green', corner_radius=0)
        self.place(x=0, y=650)

        open_btn = CTkButton(self, text='^', width=50, height=50, corner_radius=0)
        open_btn.place(x=20, y=30)

        Lock_btn = CTkButton(self, text='Lock', width=125, height=75, corner_radius=0)
        Lock_btn.place(x=100, y=30)

        logoff_btn = CTkButton(self, text='Log Off', width=125, height=75, corner_radius=0)
        logoff_btn.place(x=250, y=30)

        report_btn = CTkButton(self, text='Report Abuse', width=125, height=75, corner_radius=0)
        report_btn.place(x=400, y=30)

        item_search_btn = CTkButton(self, text='Item Search', width=125, height=75, corner_radius=0)
        item_search_btn.place(x=550, y=30)

        Return_btn = CTkButton(self, text='Returns', width=125, height=75, corner_radius=0)
        Return_btn.place(x=700, y=30)

        Funds_management = CTkButton(self, text='Funds Management', width=125, height=75, corner_radius=0)
        Funds_management.place(x=850, y=30)

class keypad(CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.configure(width=300, height=450, fg_color='green', corner_radius=0)
        self.place(x=460, y=200)

        self.widget()

    def widget(self):
        def display(var):
            global d_text
            d_text += str(var)
            lb1.configure(text=d_text)

        def clear():
            global d_text
            d_text = ''
            lb1.configure(text=d_text)

        def backspace():
            global d_text
            d_text = d_text[:-1]
            lb1.configure(text=d_text)

        lb1 = CTkLabel(self, text='', width=300, fg_color='blue')

        btn1 = CTkButton(self, text=7, width=50, height=50, command=lambda: display(7))
        btn2 = CTkButton(self, text=8, width=50, height=50, command=lambda: display(8))
        btn3 = CTkButton(self, text=9, width=50, height=50, command=lambda: display(9))
        btn4 = CTkButton(self, text=4, width=50, height=50, command=lambda: display(4))
        btn5 = CTkButton(self, text=5, width=50, height=50, command=lambda: display(5))
        btn6 = CTkButton(self, text=6, width=50, height=50, command=lambda: display(6))
        btn7 = CTkButton(self, text=1, width=50, height=50, command=lambda: display(1))
        btn8 = CTkButton(self, text=2, width=50, height=50, command=lambda: display(2))
        btn9 = CTkButton(self, text=3, width=50, height=50, command=lambda: display(3))
        btn0 = CTkButton(self, text=0, width=50, height=50, command=lambda: display(0))
        decbtn = CTkButton(self, text='.', width=50, height=50, command=lambda: display('.'))
        clear_btn = CTkButton(self, text='C', width=50, height=50, command=lambda: clear())
        back_btn = CTkButton(self, text='<<', width=50, height=50, command=lambda: backspace())
        multiply_btn = CTkButton(self, text='X', width=50, height=50)
        ok_btn = CTkButton(self, text='OK', width=50, height=140)
        lb1.place(x=0, y=0)
        btn1.place(x=20, y=75)
        btn2.place(x=80, y=75)
        btn3.place(x=140, y=75)
        btn4.place(x=20, y=140)
        btn5.place(x=80, y=140)
        btn6.place(x=140, y=140)
        btn7.place(x=20, y=205)
        btn8.place(x=80, y=205)
        btn9.place(x=140, y=205)
        btn0.place(x=20, y=270)
        decbtn.place(x=80, y=270)
        clear_btn.place(x=140, y=270)
        back_btn.place(x=200, y=75)
        multiply_btn.place(x=200, y=140)
        ok_btn.place(x=200, y=205)

class sub_menu(CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.configure(width=450, height=100, fg_color='yellow', corner_radius=0)
        self.place(x=0, y=450)

        self.widgets()

    def widgets(self):
        up_btn = CTkButton(self, text='↑', width=50, height=80)
        down_btn = CTkButton(self, text='↓', width=50, height=80)

        lb2 = CTkLabel(self, text='Balance due', font=("Arial", 20, "bold"))
        lb3 = CTkLabel(self, text='0.00', font=("Arial", 20, "bold"))
        lb4 = CTkLabel(self, text='0 items', font=("Arial", 20, "bold"))

        up_btn.place(x=20, y=10)
        down_btn.place(x=80, y=10)
        lb2.place(x=150, y=60)
        lb3.place(x=300, y=60)
        lb4.place(x=150, y=0)

software()

Some extra suggestions

I suggest you familiarise yourself with OOP in Python
Next time, provide a minimal code example don't just paste your entire code. its is much harder for people to help you


Note that sign_in() is an inner function, so argument self is not necessary and can be removed.
Also Main is a local variable inside software.__init__(), so it cannot be accessed outside that function.  You can pass it to login_page and then to its method widgets():
class software(CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        Main = main(self)
        Login_page = login_page(self, Main)
        ...

class login_page(CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent, main):
        ...
        self.widgets(main)

    def widgets(self, main):
        def sign_in():
            if login_entryfield.get() == 'user123':
                if password_entryfield.get() == 'base12':
                    print('signed in as user')
                    main.tkraise()
                else:
                    print('incorrect password')
            else:
                print('incorrect user name')
        ...


when you make Main the second argument on the 5th line it gives an error. login_page.init() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given... Is this because sign_in is a nested funciton? how do i fix that

@Samurai Answer updated to fix missing the argument parent in login_page.__init__().
